# Plyr player.source not working for youtube video

Tags: angular, plyr

I am trying to use Plyr with angular. It works fine for mp4 video file but doesn't work for youtube video. Here's the code

HTML

```
<div id="video-container" >
      <div id="vplayer" ></div>
  </div>
```

Component

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

this.player = new Plyr('#vplayer', { controls: [], fullscreen: { enabled: true, iosNative: true, container: '#video-container' }, volume: 1});
    this.player.source = {
      type: 'video' ,
      sources: [       
        {
          src: 'g2Ok2LSzBlk',
          type: 'youtube',
        },
      ],
    };

   this.player.on('ready', (event: any) => {
      this.player.muted = false;
      this.player.play(); 
    });
}
```

However, if add video id in DIV then video works fine

```
 <div id="video-container" >
      <div id="vplayer" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I think yes, I have to look back into that project. Will find what I did and post it here.